# Why switch pattern matching not work?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, visual-studio-2017

**Update:**
The problem was in the calling code. ReSharper concussed on multiple enumeration and generated this code.

```
public async Task SendItemsToMovements(IEnumerable<object> items)
{
    var enumerable = items as IList<object> ?? items.ToList();

    if (!enumerable.Any())
    {
        return;
    }
    var arrayOfArraysForUpsert = ItemsToUpsertStringConverter.GetString(enumerable);
}
```

When I leave it like this, everything works well.

```
public async Task SendItemsToMovements(IEnumerable<object> items)
{
    if (!items.Any())
    {
        return;
    }
    var arrayOfArraysForUpsert = ItemsToUpsertStringConverter.GetString(items);
}
```

**Thank you, everyone!**

I have UWP app with this code (c#7, vs2017).
When `items` is `IEnumerable<Material>` case `IEnumerable<Material> materials` not fired and fired `default`. Why?

```
    public static string GetString(IEnumerable<object> items)
    {
        switch (items)
        {
            case IEnumerable<Material> materials:

                foreach (var material in materials)
                {
                }
                break;

            case IEnumerable<Movement> movements:

                foreach (var item in movements)
                {
                }
                break;

            default:
                return string.Empty;
        }

        return "...";
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: Before the switch, add `var bob = items is IEnumerable<Material>;` What is the value of `bob`?

Comment: What is the type of `items` (as opposed to the first item contained within, which is what your screenshot is showing us but doesn't really help)?

Comment: `IEnumerable<object>` is not `IEnumerable<anything else>`. You can't assign any to the other. You probably wanted to make a generic version, which works for either `T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happened because in C# contravariance doesn't work automatically for collections. You need cast it manually.

You can try something like this

```
public static string GetString<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Material))
    {
        foreach (var material in items.Cast<Material>())
        {
        }
    }
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Movement))
    {
        foreach (var material in items.Cast<Movement>())
        {
        }
    }

    return "...";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You cant cast `IEnumerable<object> items` to  `List<Material>` that `IEnumerable<object>` is a type that have not inset of `List<Material>`.

You should get the first item to get the type and then cast it. I write the code to do it.

```
public static string GetString(IEnumerable<object> items)
 { 
    var item = items.FirstOrDefault();
    if(item == null)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    switch(item)
    {
        case Material material:
          foreach(var temp in items.Cast<Material>())
          {

          }
          break;
        case Movement movement:
        foreach (var temp in items.Cast<Movement>())
        {
        }
            break;
        default:
            return string.Empty;
    }
    return "...";

}
```

Comment: @MakeMakeluv  this case has bad performance and it isn't type safety. Use generic method

Comment: @Mr.Potkin I did not change the `GetString()` code. After all the checks, I saved the code `GetString()` and changed the code `SendItemsToMovements()`, which is specified in the Update.